# How to wait on a boolean value without busywaiting?

Tags: ruby, boolean, mutex, condition-variable

I have a Ruby application written using DRb in which a remote object signals a local object that it is done by flipping a boolean value on a local object. Currently, I wait for that boolean value like this:

```
sleep(0.05) until o.done?
```

This keeps CPU low (~0.2%, not like the 100% of a real busywait), responds quickly, but just doesn't feel right. There should be a better way of waiting on a value, or of signalling my process out of a "wait" state. Is there?

**NOTE:** It is important that the wait code yield the CPU as much as possible/tell the OS to not schedule us as much as there will be important CPU intensive tasks running at the same time.

Comment: what about setting `done` through a separate method that calls a callback after flipping the boolean?

Comment: @doesterr: that's pretty much what I'm doing, except I need to wait for it in another method, not get a callback called.

Comment: Is your concurrent code running in single process (threads) or different processes? If the latter, your simple sleep/poll seems about right to me if it's one-off, unless you want to look at re-architecting your whole application into message queues or similar top-level structure.

Comment: @NeilSlater: Different processes on different machines communicating over DRb.